# Request against localhost relative url "Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I have a visual studio 2017 [ / 2019 ] asp.net core web app project enabled with docker support using `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base` and `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build` images.

When my f5 debug instance starts up on http://localhost:44301/ I attempt to make HttpClient.SendAsync() request against relative url `/data/some.json` to pull in data making localhost debugging able to emulate security state only present in published app case.

When I f5 debug using project's IISExpress target this all works fine.  When I f5 debug against the Docker target the HttpClient.SendAsync() call against the localhost relative url, or fully qualified `https://localhost:44301/data/some.json` and `http://localhost:8081/data/some.json` paths, generates the exception with message `Cannot assign requested address`.  If I change code to load some.json from a remote url, e.g. storage account public blob path, the f5 debug Docker target does not fail on this call.

One can repro issue using the `https://github.com/myusrn/adncauthexploration.git` provided `AzWebApp1` project which also requires `https://github.com/myusrn/KK.AspNetCore.EasyAuthAuthentication.git` that is accessed using a project reference, to enable debugging contents of this nuget package. Using localhost f5 iisexpress target the issue doesn't repro. Switching to localhost f5 docker target the issue repros when debug url processing hits `KK.AspNetCore.EasyAuthAuthentication\Services\EasyAuthWithAuthMeService.cs` | line 109 `var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);`.

I'm wondering if there is some Dockerfile setting I need to be making to enable this f5 debug localhost relative url request by the asp.net core web app startup code.

Comment: Not really clear why your web app is making calls to itself.

Comment: @John, its in order to support data/some.json coming from relative path or remote url path

Answer (score 34):

I am using the same ASP.NET Core docker version and it seems work if you do this:

replace `http://localhost:<port>`

with

`http://host.docker.internal:<port>`

Try again and check if it works for you!

Comment: This worked for me. I set it in my `appsettings.json` "Urls" node.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the VS 2019-issued SSL becomes invalid.

Comment: You are a life-saver!

Comment: OMG was thrashing about on this.  Ur answer fix it. Thank u!

Comment: Life saver for this one!!

Answer (score -1):

For accessing resource from `IIS Express`, `SelfHost` and `Docker`, you could configure `HttpClient.BaseAddress` with Http Request like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    public HomeController(
        , IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        this.httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}");
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
            "data/some.json"));
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for response. That is what i'm doing already, tried both fully qualified base address and relative address requests.  In the case of a localhost f5 debug session using iisexpress it works but when I change to localhost f5 debug session using docker it generates the error message I noted.  Maybe you are suggesting something subtly different about how I create request that i'm overlooking?

Comment: @myusrn Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: thanks for continued interest in helping understand this issue and possible fixes. I added repo sources instructions to original question details.

Comment: @myusrn There are two projects, do you mean you send requests from one docker container to another?

Comment: The only project involved in repro of this issue is the AzWebApp1 project and the project it references in lieu of nuget package in order to facilitate debugging into its sources which is where the localhost /.auth/me.json relative url call happens.  Also note that I just updated the master branch with a check so that the startup.cs `options.AuthEndpoint = ".auth/me.json";` setting is enabled which is required for issue to repro.  As noted in comments using non-localhost / relative url `options.AuthEndpoint = "https://mysawestus.blob.core.windows.net/public/me.json"` makes error go away.